# Generating Negative Epoch

Tags: java, android

I am trying to generate an EPOCH value. I am using the following:

```
 int currentEpoch = ((int) System.currentTimeMillis()) / 1000;
 Log.v("EPOCH", String.valueOf(currentEpoch));
```

Below is my log:

[image]

Why is my Epoch value negative?

Comment: And what you are generating is not an "epoch".  It it time value.  An epoch is a specific point in time that is used as a reference point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`System.currentTimeMillis()` returns a `long` value. When you cast it to `int` the value is overflowing and giving you a negative number. 
Try

```
long currentEpoch =  System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;
Log.v("EPOCH", String.valueOf(currentEpoch));`
```

Answer (score 1):

In short, there's a reason that `System.currentTimeMillis()` returns a long. An int isn't large enough to store the number of milliseconds since 1970. Because it's trying to represent a value larger than it can hold, the value wraps around and becomes a negative value.